# How to activate my device connected to TV using HDMI CEC command?

Tags: television, hdmi

I have a android device which is connected to the TV's HDMI port(Lets Say that port X and assume TV has 3 HDMI port). I have ported libcec to send commands via HDMI CEC client. I am successfully able to send few CEC commands like "standby", "ON", switch the HDMI port etc.

Now my question is, How to activate the HDMI port of which my device is connected. Here in our case, it is connected to the HDMI port X. Though I am able to switch the HDMI ports, my problem is, how to detected on which port my device is connected and then switch to that corresponding port ? Or Is there any other command to activate the corresponding port ? Can anyone help me this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi i'm also facing the similar problem. Can you help me on it? How to turn off TV which is HDMI CEC enabled and connected to Nexus Player?

Comment: Hi Gopinath Android introduced TvInput Framework. In this framework it has HdmiPlaybackClient API. This API has sendStandBy() method. I'm trying to Turn off my TV(HDMI CEC Enabled) but failed. Can you help me on it.

Comment: Hi,Before using those API, make sure HDMI-CEC HAL is supported in your Android device. Otherwise, you need to implement your own HDMI-CEC HAL. The above test cases, done by me is using command line application. If you need to check it using command line app, you can use the below link to cross compile it to your platform. : [link](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec)

Comment: Hi Gopinath: Thanks for your reply. HDMI-CEC HAM is supported. And i am succeeded with One Touch Play, DisPlay status. But stand by is not working..